# Why does vista take its time to save or load directories?

Tags: windows-vista

I have a problem when it comes to saving files in certain directories in explorer on windows vista.

The problem occurs more annoyingly when I'm using a text editor, like notepad++.

As I make new files and execute the command 'save as' the explorer screen opens the directory as normal. Then after about 2 seconds, it freezes, like its trying to look for the directory or something.

I only want to save it in its default loading directory.

It takes about half a minute to unfreeze and then I can save my file.

Here is where the problem occurs:

[image: Screen freeze problem upon save]

Anyone know any similar problems or viable solutions to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This won't help your cause and isn't particularly constructive...  but just stop using Vista if at all possible.

Comment: Any weird shell extensions installed? Any mapped network drives?

Comment: no nothing, just standard vista, indexing is disabled though, do you think that is the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Is the directory in question being indexed by Vista?   It has been awhile since I have used Vista, but I would suggest turning indexing off for your my documents (if that is where you are having the issue).

Comment: It's along those lines, I disabled basically everything i.e. indexing just to make desktop computing quicker, as I hardly use my documents, the directory in the image is on the c: drive using apache/xampp. Maybe I just need to index that particular directory?

Comment: well, the only reason you need to index any directories would be if you want to be able to search for files in the indexed directories.  Do you have any need to be able to search for files in the directory in question using the search bar in Windows Explorer?